# How can i check if i have a new notification in my facebook profile C#

Tags: c#, facebook, notifications

How can i check if i have a new notification in my facebook profile using c#, .Net or the facebook sdk; or probably using all of them? I want to make an app that shows a notification on the desktop if i receive a new message.

Comment: Have you tried anything to do this? You need to show *some* effort in solving your problem, this isn't a "gimme the codez" site.

Answer (score 0):

I´d start by checking the Facebook API information, which is very extensive and clear:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/notifications/

Then if you have any issues with the code that you have written, you can post it and anyone out here will be happy to help you solving your problems with it.